# Module federation - readable chunk names in Production builds?

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have the following Webpack config for exposing modules via Module Federation:

```
...
  filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
  exposes: {
    './MainLayout': { import: './src/core/MainLayout', name: 'MainLayout' },
....
  output: {
    filename: configUtils.appJsFileName,
    chunkFilename: pathData => {
      return pathData.chunk.name && pathData.chunk.name.startsWith('main')
        ? configUtils.appJsChunkFileName
        : `chunks/${configUtils.appJsChunkFileName}`;
    },
}.
...
```

(the value of `appJsChunkFileName` is `'[name].[contenthash].chunk.min.js',`)

When i run Webpack dev-server, the chunks show up in the browser Network panel with readable names such as `MainLayout.48fj9d.js`, however in Production builds it just shows up as `94948.sjd8j.js`.

How can i fix it?

Comment: @mandy8055 added

Comment: @mandy8055 yes i am

Comment: @mandy8055 unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: @mandy8055 how can you see the chunk file name? Also - could you please share the config?

Comment: in the network tab. Here, https://github.com/mandy8055/microfrontend-demo/blob/main/packages/container/webpack/webpack.prod.js